# Creating py2app application that interacts with the filesystem

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

I have a large file that is updated on a regular basis by compiling data from another, even larger, file. I have written a script that imports the source data, transforms it so that it is compatible with the template, and then writes it to the template.

My issue is that I would like to package this into a standalone mac application for a few of my coworkers to use (who are not going to run the script from the terminal). When I create the application in alias mode, all is well; however, when I package it into a proper distributable file I get a error saying that the file (i.e. the source file) is not found.

Is there a way to make an application of this kind intereact with the filesystem on any given computer in place? To get my working directory, and to navigate to subdirectories for source data and cleaned data, I have been using:

```
codedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

and in my setup.py file I have listed all of the source files:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = ['app_data_1.xlsx',
              'app_data_2.xlsx',
              'app_data_3.xlsx']
...

setup(
     app=APP,
     data_files=DATA_FILES,
     options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
     setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` you probably end up somewhere in the local Python directory of your app, which may be `./Contents/Resources/lib/python.zip/`. From my experience with py2app, `os.getcwd()` points to the `./Contents/Resources/` directory where files provided in DATA_FILES are supposed to be located in.

If required by your app, you can place data files in subdirectories `./Contents/Resources/subdir` via

```
DATA_FILES = [
        ('subdir', ['module/subdir/app_data_1.xlsx'])
]
```

Hope this helps.